# Metrics from new job absent in Prometheus

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I installed new node_exporter.

Mertics aviable on

server01:9100/metrics

for example

```
...
node_filesystem_device_error{device="/dev/sda1",fstype="ext4",mountpoint="/boot"} 0
node_filesystem_device_error{device="/dev/sdb1",fstype="xfs",mountpoint="/data"} 0
```

wrote in config prometheus.yml new job and target

```
- job_name: node_exporter_metrics
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['server01:9100']
```

After restarted Prometheus.
Checked avialability new job and target by API, returned:

```
{"discoveredLabels":{"__address__":"server01:9100","__metrics_path__":"/metrics","__scheme__":"http","job":"node_exporter_metrics"},"labels":{"instance":"server01:9100","job":"node_exporter_metrics"},"scrapeUrl":"http://server01:9100/metrics","lastError":"","lastScrape":"2017-12-14T17:32:02.835779115+03:00","health":"up"}
```

tried to get values by new job

```
http://server01:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=node_exporter_metrics&start=1513255115&end=1513258715&step=60
```

result

```
{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":[]}}
```

How solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> http://server01:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=node_exporter_metrics&start=1513255115&end=1513258715&step=60

The name of the metric is not `node_exporter_metrics`, it's `node_filesystem_device_error`. `node_exporter_metrics` is the `job` label.

Comment: Write request: http://server01:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=node_filesystem_avail&start=1513255115&end=1513258715&step=60